# Sumar valores de un conjunto de campos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con un codigo que estoy desarrollando en javascript.

```
        function sumaTotales()
        {
            var totalsum=0;
            var j=document.getElementById("padre").childNodes;
            console.log(j);
            for(i=1;i<j.length;i++)
            {                       
                totalsum=+Number(j[i].value);
                console.log(totalsum);                  
            }

        }
```

el problema es que cuando intento sumar el valor de los campos, los campos no se suman a la variable total, sino que se sobreescriben.

> 3          generaciondinamica.html:41:14
>
> 4          generaciondinamica.html:41:14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huyyyyyyy casi lo tienes, cambia ésta linea y verás que magia:

```
totalsum=+Number(j[i].value);
```

por esta:

```
totalsum+=Number(j[i].value);
```

Te explico lo que está pasando:

En la primera le estas asignando un número positivo es decir si `Number(j[i].value` vale 5, lo que estás haciendo es esto:

```
totalsum= +5;
```

En la segunda línea lo que estas haciendo es incrementar al valor de totalsum el valor `Number(j[i].value)`.

Comment: Esto es lo que mas odio de javascript, la depuración es tan mala que se pueden cometer esos errores con muchisima facilidad.

Comment: puedes probar el código en la consola del navegador y debuguearlo ahí :)